# How is "smaller than" defined on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: definition, relations, real-numbers

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation

> *Binary relations are used in many branches of mathematics to model concepts like "is greater than", "is equal to", and "divides" in
>   arithmetic, "is congruent to" in geometry, "is adjacent to" in graph
>   theory, "is orthogonal to" in linear algebra and many more. The
>   concept of function is defined as a special kind of binary relation.
>   Binary relations are also heavily used in computer science.*

AFAIK on the set of real numbers we can define a binary relation $<$ which represents a subset of the cartesian product $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. How do we decide which pairs are contained in this subset? Do we know that by set inclusion? I know about the definition of real numbers with the concept of a Dedekind cut, so I suppose that to know which pairs are in this subset we can view the first element of any pair $(a,b)$ as a set of rationals and if it is included in the second element $b$ than we conclude that the pair $(a,b)$ is contained in the subset of the cartesian product $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and we can say that $a < b$. Am I right?

Comment: AFAIK? What does that mean?

Comment: AFAIK = as far as I know

Comment: As far as *I* know, however you decide to define the real numbers (or rationals etc...) you also have a definition of addition and multiplication, and hence subtraction.  From there you also have a definition of "positive" and "negative" numbers.  Define $a>b$ iff $a - b$ is positive.  (or equivalently $a<b$ iff $b-a$ is positive) for the usual "greater than / smaller than" binary relation

Comment: You're overthinking this.  Any subset of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ is a relation on $\Bbb R$. There's no need to think of this in terms of Dedekind cuts.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski There is if you want to define the relationship.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes I see what you're saying.  I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Well, it was confusing with the relationship definition quote. @TimRaczkowski

Comment: @JMoravitz How do you define positive and negative without defining < first?

Comment: @MingusMingusMingusMingus A Dedekind cut is positive if it contains $0$. A Dedekind cut $r$ is negative if there is a negative rational number that is not in the cut. You need to prove that a Dedekind cut which is neither positive nor negative is zero.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Then it seems quite easier to define $a<b$ as $a\subsetneq b$ and only after that define positive and negative, doesn't it?

Comment: That sentence made no sense. Did you mean "rather than after..."? @MingusMingusMingusMingus

Comment: @ThomasAndrews what Mingus$^4$ was saying was, having already decided to use Dedekind cuts, it seems that it is easier to define $<$ before positivity (that is define $<$ and, only after that, positivity).

Answer (score 2):

If you define the reals with Dedekind cuts, yes:

$$\forall a,b\in\mathbb R(a\leq b\iff a\subseteq b)$$

$$\forall a,b\in\mathbb R(a<b\iff a\subsetneq b)$$

It's a little harder to define ordering on the reals if you use Cauchy sequences. (This is because Dedekind cuts are specifically designed to "complete" the ordering of the rationals, while Cauchy sequences are designed to complete the metric space.)

Comment: There is a very nice suggestion from @JMoravitz above in the comment: "*Define a>b iff a−b is positive. (or equivalently a<b iff b−a is positive)*".

Comment: That suggestion, though, requires you to already know what "positive" means for real numbers - if we're starting "from scratch," i.e. building the real numbers via Dedekind cuts, we don't have that. It all depends on what we start with.

Comment: @notorious To be fair, that requires a definition of positive/negative which *doesn't* involve < already being defined, so I worry about my definition being circular, which is why I hesitated to put it as an answer.

Comment: @notorious Sure, that works, but it isn't "natural." Addition and subtraction are much harder definitions to add to Dedekind cuts, while set inclusion is much easier.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes you are right that a definition of positive/negative doesn't involve defining < and I think that the definition you proposed is not circular. It only involves addition and subtraction to be defined and that's all.

Comment: One thing I am curious about, is there a ***standard*** definition/reasoning for this? For example, all mathematicians using only one definition for this etc? Or I can define it the way I want it to be defined?

Comment: No, the definitions can vary. You can prove they end up with the same relationship, however. Still, if you use Dedekind cuts, it is better to stick to the subset definition because it really is more natural, and you can do it immediately, even before you define addition and multiplication. You can even prove the real numbers have the "least upper bound" property before you define the arithmetic operations. @notorious

Comment: (Addition is easy to define for Dedekind cuts, but additive inverses gets a little verbose.)

Answer (score 2):

It all comes down to how we're setting the reals up.

- If we're using Dedekind cuts, then yep, that's how to do it!
- If we're using equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, then we have to say something messier: $a<b$ if, whenever we pick representative sequences $\alpha\in a$ and $\beta\in b$, there is some $n$ such that for all $m>n$, $\alpha(m)<\beta(m)$. That is, $a<b$ if "$a$'s Cauchy sequences always eventually become smaller than $b$'s Cauchy sequences."

Comment: Do you know any materials I can read to learn more on this topic?

Comment: Hm . . . you might be interested in [the way of analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Revised-Edition-Bartlett-Mathematics/dp/0763714976). It's also worth reading Dedekind's original article - it's quite good! And on the historical side, Jeremy Gray's book "Plato's Ghost" covers much more ground, but is a hugely awesome read!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the construction you make of $\mathbb{R}$. Assuming that you already have built the operators $+,\cdot$, a simple way to notice it would be to make a subset $\mathcal{P}\subset\mathbb{R}$ which represent the positive numbers, then $a\leq b \iff b+-a\in \mathcal{P}$, where $-a$ is the additive opposite of $a$ such that $a+-a = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

In Dedekind's construction $\alpha < \beta$ is defined to mean $\alpha$ is a proper subset of $\beta$. What you say is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If we use dedekind cut to complete Q then then for a < b we must have a $\subset$ b proper subset that is.